# "Skipping service: no endpoints found" when attempting to fetch certificate with traefik 2 + cert-manager + http-01 challenge

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, cert-manager, traefik-ingress

I've been trying to get the http-01 challenge method working with traefik v2 and cert-manager, both installed through their current helm charts. The LB endpoint can be requested through the ip and hostname, and I've tested that the http host passes on letsdebug (`No issues were found with <domain>`).

Traefik lives in the `traefik` namespace, while cert-manager lives in its own `cert-manager` namespace. I've created a `ClusterIssuer` inside the `cert-manager` namespace:

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: removed@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: traefik
            ingressTemplate:
              metadata:
                namespace: cert-manager
                annotations:
                  traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web
```

The `ingressTemplate` part is my attempt at making the randomly created ingress from cert-manager map to the correct traefik endpoint - this hasn't changed anything, but I leave it in in case I've fubared anything here.

I've then created a `Certificate` and applied it - I've tried using both the cert-manager, traefik and default namespace for this, without any differing luck (the actual domain name has been replaced with domain.example.com):

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: domain.example.com
spec:
  secretName: domain-example-com-tls
  issuerRef:
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    name: letsencrypt-staging
  commonName: domain.example.com
  dnsNames:
    - domain.example.com
```

Looking at the logs for the cert-manager pod, I can see both a 404 error and then a "DNS A record error" - the DNS record error seems spurious as it can be resolved with other services and has been present for > 24hrs.

```
I0413 12:37:51.478359       1 conditions.go:201] Setting lastTransitionTime for Certificate "domain.example.com" condition "Issuing" to 2022-04-13 12:37:51.478353098 +0000 UTC m=+6998.327004050
I0413 12:37:51.760018       1 controller.go:161] cert-manager/certificates-key-manager "msg"="re-queuing item due to optimistic locking on resource" "key"="default/domain.example.com" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificates.cert-manager.io \"domain.example.com\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again"
I0413 12:37:51.769026       1 conditions.go:261] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "domain.example.com-r98k2" condition "Approved" to 2022-04-13 12:37:51.769016958 +0000 UTC m=+6998.617667914
I0413 12:37:51.836517       1 conditions.go:261] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "domain.example.com-r98k2" condition "Ready" to 2022-04-13 12:37:51.836496254 +0000 UTC m=+6998.685147170
I0413 12:37:51.868932       1 conditions.go:261] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "domain.example.com-r98k2" condition "Ready" to 2022-04-13 12:37:51.868921204 +0000 UTC m=+6998.717572135
I0413 12:37:51.888553       1 controller.go:161] cert-manager/certificaterequests-issuer-acme "msg"="re-queuing item due to optimistic locking on resource" "key"="default/domain.example.com-r98k2" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificaterequests.cert-manager.io \"domain.example.com-r98k2\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again"
E0413 12:37:53.529269       1 controller.go:210] cert-manager/challenges/scheduler "msg"="error scheduling challenge for processing" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on challenges.acme.cert-manager.io \"domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1"
I0413 12:37:55.028477       1 pod.go:71] cert-manager/challenges/http01/ensurePod "msg"="creating HTTP01 challenge solver pod" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I0413 12:37:55.237109       1 pod.go:59] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensurePod "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver pod" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Pod" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-k8wl8" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I0413 12:37:55.237350       1 service.go:43] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureService "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver Service for challenge resource" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Service" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-gvvkt" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I0413 12:37:55.237539       1 ingress.go:99] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureIngress "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver ingress" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Ingress" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-pbs7c" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
E0413 12:37:55.260608       1 sync.go:186] cert-manager/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="wrong status code '404', expected '200'" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I0413 12:37:55.299879       1 pod.go:59] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensurePod "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver pod" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Pod" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-k8wl8" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I0413 12:37:55.300223       1 service.go:43] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureService "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver Service for challenge resource" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Service" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-gvvkt" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I0413 12:37:55.300570       1 ingress.go:99] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureIngress "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver ingress" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Ingress" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-pbs7c" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
E0413 12:37:55.316802       1 sync.go:186] cert-manager/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="wrong status code '404', expected '200'" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I0413 12:38:05.261345       1 pod.go:59] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensurePod "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver pod" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Pod" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-k8wl8" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I0413 12:38:05.263416       1 service.go:43] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureService "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver Service for challenge resource" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Service" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-gvvkt" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I0413 12:38:05.263822       1 ingress.go:99] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureIngress "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver ingress" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Ingress" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-pbs7c" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
E0413 12:38:25.541964       1 sync.go:386] cert-manager/challenges/acceptChallenge "msg"="error waiting for authorization" "error"="context deadline exceeded" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
E0413 12:38:25.542087       1 controller.go:166] cert-manager/challenges "msg"="re-queuing item due to error processing" "error"="context deadline exceeded" "key"="default/domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531"
I0413 12:38:30.542803       1 pod.go:59] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensurePod "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver pod" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Pod" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-k8wl8" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I0413 12:38:30.543062       1 service.go:43] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureService "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver Service for challenge resource" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Service" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-gvvkt" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I0413 12:38:30.543218       1 ingress.go:99] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureIngress "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver ingress" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Ingress" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-pbs7c" "related_resource_namespace"="default" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
E0413 12:38:46.682039       1 sync.go:386] cert-manager/challenges/acceptChallenge "msg"="error waiting for authorization" "error"="acme: authorization error for domain.example.com: 400 urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns: During secondary validation: DNS problem: query timed out looking up A for domain.example.com; DNS problem: query timed out looking up AAAA for domain.example.com" "dnsName"="domain.example.com" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="domain.example.com-r98k2-2809069211-587139531" "resource_namespace"="default" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
E0413 12:38:46.888731       1 controller.go:102] ingress 'default/cm-acme-http-solver-pbs7c' in work queue no longer exists
```

Looking at Traefik's pod log, I can see that the ingress gets created, but that Traefik is unable to route any requests to it because it can't find the endpoint (this is what I tried to fix with the annotation in the ingressTemplate above):

```
time="2022-04-13T12:37:57Z" level=error msg="Skipping service: no endpoints found" providerName=kubernetes namespace=default servicePort="&ServiceBackendPort{Name:,Number:8089,}" ingress=cm-acme-http-solver-pbs7c serviceName=cm-acme-http-solver-gvvkt
time="2022-04-13T12:38:46Z" level=error msg="Skipping service: no endpoints found" serviceName=cm-acme-http-solver-gvvkt servicePort="&ServiceBackendPort{Name:,Number:8089,}" providerName=kubernetes ingress=cm-acme-http-solver-pbs7c namespace=default
time="2022-04-13T12:38:46Z" level=error msg="Cannot create service: service not found" servicePort="&ServiceBackendPort{Name:,Number:8089,}" providerName=kubernetes ingress=cm-acme-http-solver-pbs7c namespace=default serviceName=cm-acme-http-solver-gvvkt
time="2022-04-13T12:38:46Z" level=error msg="Cannot create service: service not found" servicePort="&ServiceBackendPort{Name:,Number:8089,}" namespace=default providerName=kubernetes serviceName=cm-acme-http-solver-gvvkt ingress=cm-acme-http-solver-pbs7c
```

And there's where I'm stuck currently, since the plan is to use Traefik's `IngressRoute` CRD for exposing hosts and not use regular ingress entries. Another option would be to test the experimental Gateway support, but as this is the initial setup for a prod cluster I'm not planning to go down that route yet.

Any ideas or further debug information that could be useful?

Comment: Hi, there did you get any assistance on this, I'm experiencing the same issue?

Comment: @LibbyLebyane Sorry, never got any longer; switched first to the caddy ingress controller, but had some issues with that as well, so I ended up with the default nginx ingress controller for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have faced the same issue and the problem was related to the fact, that the Ingress generated by the `certificate manger` contained the `Ingress Controller` reference using the deprecated Annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class`.

What we wanted:

```
spec:
  ingressClassName: my-traefik-controller
```

What we got:

```
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "my-traefik-controller"
```

This way, the `traefik` Ingress Controlelr found the Ingress, but was not able to find the service.
There is a whole discussion on this topic in the [cert-manger Github repo](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/4821).

The solution was to use the [cert-manager Annotation](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/ingress/#supported-annotations) `acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"` on an existing Ingress.

```
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: my-issuer
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
  spec:
    ingressClassName: my-traefik-controller
```

This way, only the existing Ingress (containing the correct `ingressClassName` reference) gets modified and no new solver Ingress gets created.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error while setting up a home Kubernetes environment. In my case the issue was NAT loopback/hairpinning/reflection, as certain ISPs restrict the ability to reach hosts within a private network using the public IP address.

Solution involved modifying the `coredns` configmap and adding the following entry:

```
rewrite name domain.example.com traefik.<traefik-namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

Then simply restart `coredns` pod. Hope it will help someone.